# Import CSV to QGIS with z-values in column 4

Tags: qgis, csv

I would like to import CSV into QGIS, but the z-values are listed in column 4. I didn't find out how I could specify that the values are not in column 3 but in column 4.

Edit: Added a screenshot
[image]

Comment: Are you using the Add Delimited Text Layer button? Do you want to use the z-value in a geometry or just as an attribute?

Comment: Yes, I did. And I want to use the z.values in a geometry.

Answer (score 1):

At this stage (2.8) QGIS doesn't support z on geometries.